# Why does Backbone JS .extend() always return an empty function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm new to backbone js and am having difficulty at a seemingly trivial aspect.

Whenever I call Backbone.Collection.extend, Backbone.Model.extend or Backbone.View.extend, what returns is an empty function rather than an object with inherited properties.

Examples:

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
});

console.log("View:");
console.log(view);
```

Console.log shows:

```
View:
function()
```

And nothing happens if you click on "function()", it's just an empty function with no properties.

Everywhere that I attempt to extend Backbone objects, I get the same problem. As I've explored the issue, I tried this:

```
var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    add: function() {
        console.log("Add gets called");
        return {};
    }
});

console.log("Collection:");
console.log(collection);
console.log(collection.add());
```

Console shows:

```
Collection:
function()
TypeError: collection.add is not a function
```

I don't think there is anything unusual about my requirejs setup, so I'm hoping someone with more experience using underscore and backbone's extend() can tell me why they would sometimes return empty functions.

Any suggestions as to areas I might look into to solve this would be welcomed. Being new to the libraries involved, I'm kind of scratching my head about how to solve this so I can move on with my app.

Comment: `extend` returns a constructor, you should use the `new` keyword for creating an instance, then you can call the `add` function.

Comment: var collection = new Backbone.Collection.extend({}); you may use some thing like this

Comment: That makes perfect sense and works as expected, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **extend** Backbone.Collection.extend(properties, [classProperties])
>
> To create a Collection class of your own, extend Backbone.Collection, providing instance properties, as well as optional classProperties to be attached directly to the collection's constructor function.

So in your case `view` is a `Collection class`, try to instantiate it with the `new` keyword :

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
});

console.log("View:");
console.log(new view()); // Here
```

Comment: off the top off my head i still don't get why just assigning view =  new  Backbone.View.extend();

does not work